# Where should JDBC initiated in web-applications?

Tags: jdbc, web-applications, jax-rs

I want to achieve a connection right in the beginning, and I don't want this constructor to be called again and again, as it always goes into catch, throwing exceptions.

I have initiated the JDBC in the constructor of a class Database,which looks something like this, with annotation.

```
@Singleton
@Named
public class Database{

    public Database(){

        try {
            MysqlDataSource source; //and connection settings here

       javax.naming.Context ctx = new InitialContext();

            ctx.bind(Constants.CONTEXT_DATABASE_ID, source);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Web.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }


}
```

Thing is, everytime I call a method on this class, its constructor gets called, and therefore, the namecontext is called in try/catch method. If the query to do database will be more, is there a way to avoid getting this exception caught every time.

I think this might be one of the solutions. In other words, is there a way to check if the naming Context of javax.naming.Context already contains the instance of the JDBC?

What hould I do?

```
Content: true
Type: detectCustomCollations
Content: false
Type: allowPublicKeyRetrieval
Content: false
Type: dontCheckOnDuplicateKeyUpdateInSQL
Content: false
Type: readOnlyPropagatesToServer
Content: true
] at location [service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.global_Etiki_Users] [Root exception is org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.global_Etiki_Users is already registered]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NamingUtils.namingException(NamingUtils.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:253)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:260)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:262)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at com.rockink.etiki.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:51) [classes:]
    at com.rockink.etiki.database.Database$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.<init>(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanProxyInstantiator.newInstance(SessionBeanProxyInstantiator.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.create(SessionBean.java:149) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:840) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.inject(WeldInjectionContext.java:39) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:51) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it.

After testing, the class calls only once @postconstruct, and calls constructors every time if its method is called and is annotated with @Inject in the class from where the call is made.

So, put the above code in @postconstruct, you wont get error anymore.